# Deployed on WildFly but still getting 404

Tags: jboss, wildfly-9

I am referring to the [following helloworld example](http://www.thejavageek.com/2015/12/16/jax-rs-hello-world-example-with-wildfly/)

My application is successfully deployed on my eclipse using WildFly 9.x as shown in the screenshot and the console log below:

[image]

Here's the eclipse console log details :

```
14:08:16,447 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.4.3.Final
14:08:17,156 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
14:08:17,293 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) starting
14:08:19,873 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'job-repository-type' in the resource at address '/subsystem=batch' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
14:08:19,890 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
14:08:19,908 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found JAX-RS_examples.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called JAX-RS_examples.war.dodeploy
14:08:19,953 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
14:08:19,993 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
14:08:20,007 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
14:08:20,075 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
14:08:20,106 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
14:08:20,213 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
14:08:20,183 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
14:08:20,179 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
14:08:20,110 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
14:08:20,164 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
14:08:20,164 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
14:08:20,136 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 4 core threads with 32 task threads based on your 2 available processors
14:08:20,106 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
14:08:20,377 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
14:08:20,684 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.2.5.Final)
14:08:20,975 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
14:08:20,985 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
14:08:21,016 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.2.Final
14:08:21,158 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
14:08:21,194 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path D:\Users\dan\wildfly-9.0.2.Final/welcome-content
14:08:21,246 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
14:08:21,264 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
14:08:21,727 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
14:08:22,413 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\Users\dan\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\deployments
14:08:22,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "JAX-RS_examples.war" (runtime-name: "JAX-RS_examples.war")
14:08:22,885 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 5.0.0.Final
14:08:23,423 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
14:08:25,131 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.thejavageek.jaxrs.ExampleApplication
14:08:25,203 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
14:08:25,283 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /JAX-RS_examples
14:08:25,463 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "JAX-RS_examples.war" (runtime-name : "JAX-RS_examples.war")
14:08:25,939 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
14:08:25,941 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
14:08:25,942 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) started in 9899ms - Started 272 of 453 services (221 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

I am trying to access the application like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:9990/JAX-RS_examples/rest/HelloWorld/sayHello
```

And getting 404 not found.

Came across similar thread but can't figure out :

[WildFly running, project deployed, but 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537154/wildfly-running-project-deployed-but-404)

Comment: Are you sure "rest" is part of the context URL?

Comment: So there's `@ApplicationPath("/rest")` used in the `ExampleApplication` class. Any other place you would like me to check?

Comment: Okay, then check the deployment, I was using WildFly and I also had a lot of this 404 when running the applications, basically they were two reasons, 1. an error that maybe you are not spoting in the log, 2. the weird way context deployments are given

Comment: Hmm, I am trying to create a new dynamic project with "“Generate web.xml deployment descriptor" and see how it goes.

Comment: `14:08:25,463 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "JAX-RS_examples.war" (runtime-name : "JAX-RS_examples.war")`... try adding war to the URL

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166564/discussion-between-dan-and-keso).

Comment: You are using the wrong port, it should be http://127.0.0.1:8080/JAX-RS_examples/rest/HelloWorld/sayHello

Comment: @KESO `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` shows WildFly page. But the whole URL(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/JAX-RS_examples/rest/HelloWorld/sayHello`) doesn't work which is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

someone already told you.
You call your REST service with the port 9990.
But, this port is form the admin console.

by default, the correct port should be 8080. So, just call:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/JAX-RS_examples/rest/HelloWorld/sayHello

Comment: It says `404, Not Found ` when I tried. What else can be the problem? I tried with 8080 but it didn't work. When I use http://127.0.0.1:9990, it changes to this URL http://127.0.0.1:9990/error/index_win.html and shows the WildFly screen.

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` shows WildFly page. But the whole URL(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/JAX-RS_examples/rest/HelloWorld/sayHello`) doesn't work which is strange.

Comment: port 9990 is the admin port. so it shows the wildfly homepage. Did you maybe change the port for the project?

Comment: I don't think so I changed anything related to port at my end. If I had to investigate that, where I could check?

Comment: Do I need to define something in `web.xml` ? I didn't create any deployment descriptor while creating dynamic web project in eclipse.

Comment: It finally worked when I changed WildFly version to 10 from 9.

Comment: @Dan: Did you know why it worked after changing version from 9 to 10?

Comment: @CongBangDO Sorry, I don't remember :(

Answer (score 1):

The runtime name needs to have a `.war` estension.

[image: WildFly deploment]